# Submitting form data to multiple tables. NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hey could someone please help me submit this form? Here is my ViewModel that I made. This is my third day trying to pick up MVC so I'm still new to this.

```
public class EmployeeAllData
{
    public Employees Employees { get; set; }
    public PermissionModel PermissionModel { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my controller for the form submit. I'm starting with the permission table and I'm not having any luck. It keeps giving me this error: NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code. I tried hard coding values and it updated the permissions table just fine. I can't find out why I'm not getting a value back from Employees.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(EmployeeAllData viewModel)
    {

        var permission = new PermissionModel
        {
            EmployeesId = Convert.ToByte(viewModel.Employees.Id),
            TimeStamp = DateTime.Now,
            PermissionVal = viewModel.Employees.Permissions
        };

        _context.PermissionModels.Add(permission);
        _context.SaveChanges();


        return RedirectToAction("EmployeeList", "Employee");
    }
```

Any ideas?

***UPDATE***
I think my problem is with my ViewModel. The code below runs fine and creates a new employee in the database.

```
    public ActionResult Create(Employees employees)
    {
        _context.Employeeses.Add(employees);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("EmployeeList", "Employee");
    }
```

Comment: because `viewModel.Employees` is null ? You need to make sure that your form fields has names matching to the property hierarchy for model binder to successfully map the child properties

Comment: I just can't understand why it works when I don't use the viewModel but when I try to use the viewModel it returns all the values as null.

Comment: First, your pluraization is very confusing (Employees is a single employee and employeeses is a collection). That will confuse a lot of people. Second, your EmployeeAllData viewmodel has your entity model nested inside it screwing up your model binding as Shyju said. Your viewmodel should have all the properties your view uses at the top level and then use a tool like Automapper to simplify the copying back and forth to your entity model. You generally don't want to expose your entity models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not need to use a viewModel. Here is my final code that now works.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Employees employees)
    {


        _context.Employeeses.Add(employees);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        var permission = new PermissionModel()
        {
            EmployeesId = Convert.ToByte(employees.Id),
            TimeStamp = DateTime.Now,
            PermissionVal = employees.Permissions
        };

        _context.PermissionModels.Add(permission);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("EmployeeList", "Employee");
    }
```

Comment: That's probably because "employees" is the name of the form field :) You have to make sure that they match